# Proving that the following limit doesn't exist

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\dfrac{x-y+x^2+y^2}{x+y}$$
$$\{(x,y):x+y>0\}$$
$$x:=0 \Rightarrow \dfrac{-y+y^2}{y}y-1$$
$$y:=0 \Rightarrow \dfrac{x-x^2}{x}=1-x$$

Is it enough to prove that?

Comment: The explanation could be much clearer, but the general idea is right.

Comment: Your proofs will be clearer for your audience (and for yourself) if you explain your ideas. It is not enough to write down equations.

Answer (score 0):

plugging $x=1/n,y=1/\sqrt{n}$ in the given term and let $n$ tends to infinity we get $-1$ as the searched limit.
for $x=1/\sqrt{n}$ and $y=1/n$ we get $1$